# Call non-static C++ member functions through emscripten->webassembly

Tags: c++, emscripten, non-static

I've been having some issues with trying to call non-static member functions of my C++ classes in JS. The problem being the Emscripten compiler does not compile non-static functions, when I throw static in front it compiles!

Is there a way to wrap the non-static members in an emscripten class or function? I'm very new to this compiler

heres the code top down:

**bindings.cpp**

```
#include <emscripten.h>
#include <emscripten/bind.h>
#include <string>
#include "src/Interact.h"

using namespace emscripten;

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(Interact) {
    function("playerMove", optional_override([]() -> std::string {
        return Interact::playerMove();
    }));
}
```

**interact.cpp**

```
#include "Interact.h"

using namespace std;

Interact::Interact() {}

string Interact::playerMove() {
    return "moved player";
}
```

**Interact.h**

```
class Interact {
public:
    Interact();
    static std::string playerMove();
```

but say I want to have a variable thats accessed between several methods, or keepAlive a Maps object where all the maps to my game are stored, I would rather not have to initialize it everytime i use it.. rather initialize it once and make calls to it.

Comment: The Emscripten documentation on binding C++ [classes](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/embind.html#classes) should be useful.

Comment: Why the optional_override? Can you just export the playerMove function?

Comment: @kalwalt I dont know, I just saw it used on most bindings, reading the documentation is a bit confusing